# How to drag and drop blocks of code using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make this faster?
Here is its GIF

[image: Here is its GIF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your 4 values below and cut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), then place your cursor to the right of your first line comma, hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> then press down on the arrow key 4 times to multi-select your target lines. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the values.

Comment: Soon after putting this question, I found this way myself, but I'm still looking for a way to do it more quickly.

Comment: The drag/drop example you used in your question wasn't even available to me until I just downloaded Version 1.13.1, but I didn't easily see this functionality in the release notes either.. I'll edit again later if I come across a faster way, glad you can keep moving though for now!

Comment: Best I've found at the moment here, so maybe multiline support isn't yet available: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_preview-drag-and-drop-selected-text